# How to change Gradle install tasks

Tags: android, gradle

I want to edit gradle task named *installDebug*. Where is the task (or script) located? Maybe this script is located in binary code and I'm not change that?

Really, I want run edit something option for `adb`.
Example: My task must contain:

1. Run adb like "adb connect 192.168.1.2:5555"
2. Run "debugInstall" gradles task, directly.
3. Do something, like - adb  then open apk on my adb server..

What I should do:
Edit *debugTask* if possible?
Or edit *build.grade* and make own task script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the tasks are located in `build.gradle` script itself or in the plugin that is applied at the beginning of the script.

*installDebug* task is provided by as far as I remember *android* plugin. Every single task consists of actions that are executed sequentially. [Here's](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) the place to start.

You can *extend* a task adding action to the beginning of at the end of internal actions list.

So:

```
//this piece of code will run *adb connect* in the background
installDebug.doFirst {
   def processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(['adb', 'connnect', '192.168.1.2:5555'])
   processBuilder.start()
}

installDebug.doLast {
   //Do something, like - adb then open apk on my adb server..
}
```

Here, two actions were added to *installDebug* task. If you run `gradle installDebug`, first action will be run, then the task itself and finally the second action that is defined. That's all in general.

Comment: No, this is not possible. What You can do is to write a script that will be executing all those commands and run that script or run multiple commands in the way the single one is run in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a task to your build.gradle, and call it in command line.
This is what I have done :

task adbConnect(type: Exec) {
   commandLine 'adb', 'connect', '192.168.200.92'
}

then I call gradle adbConnect connectedCheck, but you can use gradle adbConnect debugInstall

Comment: No, you can put several commands one after the other. gradle adbConnect debugInstall, will run adbConnect, then debugInstall. I sometimes add "clean" at first command.